# Suggestion for Optimization with hashmathch

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

A query is consuming more than a hour when we called it from a Cron Job at night (Other expensive queries run at that time as well). But when I run it in the off hours the output comes within few seconds. I tried with below two different versions of query to retrieve the data but it still consumes time.

Query 1 Execution Plan 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkq9cJ3gz

Query 2 Execution Plan 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByaBNWhgG

Any suggestions

@SteveFord here is the structure for 
T_CST_GEOADDR                                                             CUST_ID   varchar
LATITUDE    float
LONGITUDE   float
Cust_Detail_MD5 varchar
LAST_RECEIVE_DATE   datetime                                                                  and indexes are                                                                                              cl_t_cst_geoaddr_cust_id clustered located on PRIMARY    CUST_ID
IX_t_cst_geoaddr_Cust_ID_RECEIVE_DATE   nonclustered located on PRIMARY CUST_ID, LAST_RECEIVE_DATE

For the table T_CST_ADDRESS

Customer_ID nvarchar
Address_Line_1  nvarchar
Address_Line_2  nvarchar
City    nvarchar
State   nvarchar
ZIP nvarchar
Foreign_Postal_Code nvarchar
Country_ID  nvarchar
Address_Type_ID nvarchar
Session_Id  varchar
Receive_Time    datetime

and indexes are

IDX_T_CST_ADDRESS   clustered located on PRIMARY    Customer_ID, Address_Type_ID
ix_t_cst_address_customer_id_include_rec_time   nonclustered located on PRIMARY Customer_ID

Comment: see wating while qurey running. And remove NOLOCK

Comment: It would be helpful to see table structures / indexes

Comment: @SteveFord here is the structure